# Product Combinations URL is not unique in Prestashop

Tags: url, attributes, prestashop, combinations, product

I am using Prestashop and facing problem with URL when i change product combination.

*Please open link bellow to view issue.*
http://www.softfolds.co.uk/384-charlotte-thomas-chloe-pencil-pleat-curtains-tie-backs-fabric-compostion-50-cotton-amp-50-polyester-curtain-heading-pencil-pleat.html

[image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgmtB.jpg)

by clicking on image-1, My url is not changing anymore. Before it was changing. Like in the end it should be something  like this **"heading-pencil-pleat.html#/Panel_Width_66_Drop_72".**

In the end i want different url for different combinations.